# Transactions approved by Authorize.Net with incorrect expiration date and CVS number

Tags: vb.net, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have currently processed a credit card using Authorize.net with Card Present settings. The great thing is that the card is being transacted but when i use the same card with different expiry date or a different cvs number the card is still being transacted. This shouldnt happen. Here is the code that im using in VB.NET.

Am i missing any settings?. This transaction is on test mode.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal authID As String, _
                   ByVal authPassword As String, _
                   ByVal authTransKey As String, _
                   ByVal serverType As AuthServerTypeEnum, _
                   ByVal cardHolderName As String, _
                   ByVal cardNumber As String, _
                   ByVal expiryMonth As String, _
                   ByVal expiryYears As String, _
                   ByVal issuenumber As Integer, _
                   ByVal cvs As Integer, _
                   ByVal issueMonth As String, _
                   ByVal issueYear As String, _
                   ByVal fullName As String, _
                   ByVal address1 As String, _
                   ByVal address2 As String, _
                   ByVal townCity As String, _
                   ByVal county As String, _
                   ByVal country As String, _
                   ByVal postCode As String, _
                   ByVal amount As String)

        Me._AuthServerType = AuthServerTypeEnum.Test
        'Me._AuthLoginID = "xxxxxx"
        'Me._AuthTransKey = "xxxxxx"
        Me._AuthLoginID = "xxxxxx"
        Me._AuthTransKey = "xxxxxx"

        Dim objInf As New NameValueCollection(30)
        Dim objRetInf As New NameValueCollection(30)

        objInf.Add("x_version", _AuthVersion)
        objInf.Add("x_delim_data", "True")
        objInf.Add("x_login", Me.AuthLoginID)
        objInf.Add("x_password", Me.AuthPassword)
        objInf.Add("x_tran_key", Me.AuthTransKey)
        objInf.Add("x_relay_response", "False")



        Select Case Me.AuthServerType
            Case AuthServerTypeEnum.Live
                objInf.Add("x_test_request", "false")
            Case Else
                objInf.Add("x_test_request", "True")
        End Select

        objInf.Add("x_delim_char", ",")
        objInf.Add("x_encap_char", "|")

        objInf.Add("x_first_name", fullName)
        'objInf.Add("x_last_name", "Patel")
        objInf.Add("x_address", address1)
        objInf.Add("x_city", townCity)
        objInf.Add("x_state", county)
        objInf.Add("x_zip", postCode)
        objInf.Add("x_country", country)

        objInf.Add("x_description", "Description of Order")

        objInf.Add("x_card_num", cardNumber.Replace(" ", ""))
        objInf.Add("x_exp_date", expiryMonth.ToString & "/" & expiryYears.ToString)
        objInf.Add("x_market_type", "2")
        objInf.Add("x_device_type", "5")
        objInf.Add("x_response_format", "1")

        objInf.Add("x_card_code", cvs)

        objInf.Add("x_method", "CC")
        objInf.Add("x_type", "AUTH_CAPTURE")
        objInf.Add("x_amount", "1")

        objInf.Add("x_currency_code", "USD")

        Dim objRetBytes() As Byte
        Dim objRetVals() As String
        Dim strError As String = String.Empty

        Try

            objRetBytes = Me.WebClientRequest.UploadValues(Me.WebClientRequest.BaseAddress, objInf)
            objRetVals = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objRetBytes).Split(",".ToCharArray())

            If True Then

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a coding issue.

An incorrect expiration date and/or CVV number will not necessarily cause a transaction to be declined. It is not uncommon for an incorrect expiration date to be provided by a customer so many banks do not decline sales for this reason. Additionally, CVV is just a tool for determining fraud risk per transaction. A mismatch simply means the chance of risk is higher and it's up to the merchant to decide if they want to accept or reject the transaction. But the transaction will not be declined for it as it is not a factor in the approval process for most card issuing banks.

Comment: the company wnats the expiry date and security number to be handled so what do i do?, thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: @Trikam I'm not experienced with card present so hopefully this makes sense and applies to you. If the card is swiped you can capture and display the expiration date on the screen. Then the cashier can verify it matches what is embossed on the card. As for the CVV number I don't know any way to verify it other then to verify it was typed in correctly (assuming it was a keyed transaction). After the transaction is processed you will receive a response indicating whether the CVV number was correct or not. You can display a warning if it's not and always void the transaction if needed.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: @Samyer Yes, this is still true